# How to give Page break while using wkhtmltopdf?

Tags: html, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

Please help me with the option that will give page break. I have three exercises (Containing text)in my HTML file which is converted to PDF as a report. I wanted to add a page break after every exercise so that every exercise starts with a new page in the PDF. what is the solution here.
Do I need to handle this via css to using the wkhtnltopdf options and how? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS property "page-break-after" or "break-after".

```
<div class="exercise">
...
</div>


<style>
    @media print {
        .exercise {
            break-after: always;
        }
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this will reflect on the .html page. Will the page break work on the PDF as well as I am using wkhtmltopdf?

Comment: Yes. I have a project using wkhtmltopdf and it works fine. I updated my answer a bit; try wrap your CSS in media query so it only reflects on print.